# Problem with veryfing contract

Tags: compiler, bscscan, version-pragma, verification

Hi I had my smart contract previously deployed and verified. However mythril warned me of floating pragma so I changed version explicitly to

```
pragma solidity 0.8.1;
```

I deployed it tot testnet using hardhat, flatten my file with hardhat, cleaned multiple spdx. And I have trouble to verify.

In my flat file I can see

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

I can't verify it neither with 0.8.1 nor 0.8.0
What can I do ?